# Process being kept open "some where"

Tags: windows, filesystems, outlook

I've got an instance of the following error.

[image]

The file is an outlook .pst file the has become corrupt, I'd like to move the file to another location and run the inbox repair tool.

I have shut down the PC that was running outlook, and it still comes up as locked when I attempt to move the file from one location on a filer to another (to run the inbox repair tool)

Comment: I just restored from a previous version and it worked.

Answer (score 0):

I just restored from a previous version and it worked